# Unknown plugin "transform-object-assign" specified in babelrc

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I was having issues running my react app in IE. So I installed a babel plugin and installed it. It works fine on my colleague's machine but I'm getting an error.

```
 ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-object-assign" specified in "C:\\Users\\vgudipati\\Desktop\\gssp-servicing-multitenancy\\.babelrc" at 1, attempted to resolve relative to "C:\\Users\\vgudipati\\Desktop\\gssp-servicing-multitenancy"
```

My babelrc looks like this

```
{
    "presets": [
      "es2015-ie",
      "stage-0",
      "react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-node-env-inline",
        "transform-object-assign"
    ]
}
```

package json.

```
{
  "name": "remix-demo",
  "version": "0.9.11",
  "description": "Remix demo",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "build:client": "gulp build:client",
    "build:server": "guilp build:server",
    "build": "gulp build",
    "serve": "gulp serve",
    "start": "gulp",
    "run": "gulp run"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "gi+https://stash.infusion.com/scm/gssp/remix-demo.git"
  },
  "author": "MetLife",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE",
  "dependencies": {
    "babylon": "^6.7.0",
    "base64toblob": "0.0.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.3.4",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.6",
    "classnames": "^2.2.3",
    "compression": "1.6.2",
    "d3": "^3.5.16",
    "es6-map": "^0.1.3",
    "es6-symbol": "^3.0.2",
    "filesaver.js": "^0.2.0",
    "font-awesome": "4.3.0",
    "graphql": "^0.4.18",
    "gssp-common-lib": "0.9.30",
    "gssp-servicing-configurations": "0.9.30",
    "gssp-servicing-lib": "0.9.30",
    "helmet": "3.1.0",
    "immutable": "^3.7.6",
    "immutable-reducers": "^1.1.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "mongojs": "^2.3.0",
    "namespaces-js": "0.5.4",
    "numeral": "^1.5.3",
    "on-headers": "1.0.1",
    "react": "^15",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.28.3",
    "react-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^0.0.22",
    "react-google-maps": "^4.10.1",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^0.5.2",
    "react-input-calendar": "^0.1.20",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.1",
    "react-toggle": "2.1.1",
    "react-truncate": "^2.0.3",
    "react-typeahead": "^1.1.6",
    "redux": "^3.3.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.0.1",
    "remix-client": "0.9.41",
    "remix-common": "0.9.41",
    "remix-server": "0.9.41",
    "winston": "2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-node-env-inline": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015-ie": "^6.6.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.7.2",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "browserify": "^13.0.0",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "env-manager": "^0.2.2",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^4.3.0",
    "fs.extra": "^1.3.2",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "3.1.0",
    "gulp-babel": "6.1.2",
    "gulp-bless": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "2.0.3",
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "2.0.0",
    "gulp-if": "2.0.0",
    "gulp-inject": "4.0.0",
    "gulp-install": "0.6.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "1.2.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "2.0.6",
    "gulp-replace": "0.5.4",
    "gulp-sass": "2.2.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "1.6.0",
    "gulp-tasks-registrator": "0.2.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.5.3",
    "gulp-util": "3.0.7",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.5",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "vinyl-transform": "^1.0.0",
    "watchify": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      [
        "babelify"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Please help.

Thank you!

Comment: You have `babel-plugin-transform-object-assign` as a dependency, but you might not have installed it. Try re-installing. `rm -rf node_modules; npm install`

Comment: Getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Remove  .babelrc file from your packagge directory before building
       rm  "C:\Users\vgudipati\Desktop\gssp-servicing-multitenancy\.babelrc"